# UInavigationController Navbar wont hide

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Cant seem to get navbar to hide. I am certain this should work as I used it before but this time its not working. Not sure if its because of the xcode 6 update.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];   //it hides
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];    // it shows
}
```

Comment: Is self.navigationController nil?

Comment: what do you mean by that? I've implemented a navigation controller via storyboard. Editor----->embed in ---->navigation Controller

Comment: You can log self.navigationController to see if it exist.